# Неопределённая ошибка в тесте на Кармайкловы числа

Tags: python, теория-чисел

Никак ни могу понять где ошибка в коде, все вроде выходит из определения чисел Кармайкла, но тем не менее программа их не видит.

```
k = int(input())


def is_prime(x):
    for j in range(2, x // 2 + 1):
        if x % j == 0:
            return False
    return True


def is_fermat_prime(x):
    for q in range(2, x):
        if q ** (x - 1) % x != 1:
            return False
    return True


def is_carmichael(x):
    if is_prime(x) is False & is_fermat_prime(x) is True:
        return True
    else:
        return False


exit = []
for i in range(2, k):
    if is_carmichael(i) is True:
        exit.append(i)

print(exit)
```

Я проверял правильность написания функций is_prime и is_fermat_prime, ошибка вероятнее всего в is_fermat_prime.

Answer (score 2):

### Проблемы

1. > [Число Кармайкла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0) - составное *n*, которое удовлетворяет сравнению *b<sup>n-1</sup> ≡ 1 (mod n)* для всех целых *b*, **взаимно простых** с *n*.

   В вашем коде нет проверки взаимной простоты.
2. Выражение `is_prime(x) is False & is_fermat_prime(x) is True` вычисляется не так как вы ожидаете.

   Например `False is False & True is True` вычисляется в `False`. Потому что приоритет `&` выше чем приоритет `is` (см. [таблицу приоритетов](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)). После расстановки скобок получится `False is (False & True) is True` → `False is False is True`. Компилятор Питона транслирует такие выражения аналогично `10 < x < 20` и превращает его в `(False is False) and (False is True)`, который вычисляется в `True and False` → `False`.

   Поправить можно, расставив скобки: `(is_prime(x) is False) & (is_fermat_prime(x) is True)`.

   Но и у этого выражения есть свои проблемы. `&` медленно обрабатывает логические значения - правая часть вычисляется даже если левая уже вернула `False`, `and` этого не делает, существенно экономя время на вызове `is_fermat_prime`.

   Операторы `is` вообще в нормальном коде не должны встречаться. Лучше написать `not is_prime(x) and is_fermat_prime(x)`.

После исправления код заработает. Чтобы работало быстрее, проверку на простоту делайте до корня из `x` а для вычисления степени по модулю используйте [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). У неё есть третий параметр - модуль.

### Теорема Корсельта

> составное число *n* является числом Кармайкла тогда и только тогда, когда *n* свободно от квадратов и для каждого простого делителя *p* числа *n* число *p - 1* делит *n - 1*.

Можно искать числа Кармайкла по их разложению на простые.

```
import math


def factors(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        e = 0
        while n % 2 == 0:
            n //= 2
            e += 1
        yield 2, e

    i = 3

    n_sqrt = math.isqrt(n)
    while i <= n_sqrt:
        if n % i == 0:
            e = 0
            while n % i == 0:
                n //= i
                e += 1
            yield i, e
            n_sqrt = math.isqrt(n)
        i += 2

    if n > 1:
        yield n, 1


def is_carmichael(n):
    for p, e in factors(n):

        # free of squares
        if e > 1:
            return False

        # divisibility
        if (n - 1) % (p - 1) != 0:
            return False

    # is not prime?
    return p != n


def main():
    for n in range(2, int(input())):
        if is_carmichael(n):
            print(n)


main()
```

За шесть секунд программа находит 43 числа Кармайкла до миллиона:

> ```
> $ time echo 1000000 | python korselt.py | wc -l
> 43
>
> real  0m5.152s
> user  0m5.140s
> sys   0m0.004s
> ```

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помогли, я в питоне всего меньше недели и ещё не разобрался с приоритетами логических операторов, про теорему Корсельта я слышал и понимал что так будет быстрее, но первоначально я хотел написать код опираясь на определения